# Returning the remaining mean in an array

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Given an integer array arr, return the mean of the remaining integers after removing the smallest 5% and the largest 5% of the elements.

I've already attempted this problem and I believe that I am right however it isn't outputting the results i was hoping for.

Example:

```
Input: arr = [6,2,7,5,1,2,0,3,10,2,5,0,5,5,0,8,7,6,8,0]
Output: 4.00000
```

My code:

```
double trimMean(vector<int> &arr)
{
    sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
    int length = arr.size();
    int smallest = round(0.05 * length);
    int largest = round(0.95 * length);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = smallest; i <= largest; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    double average = sum / (largest - smallest);
    return average;
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What output are you expecting?  Try `double average = sum / (largest - smallest + 1);` to include all the elements.

Comment: *"I believe that I am right however it isn't outputting the results i was hoping for."* -- Are you accepting this belief in the face of evidence to the contrary, or are you of the belief that you were hoping for incorrect output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line:

```
double average = sum / (largest - smallest);
```

the right hand side consists of only `int`s and so you are doing integer division, and then assigning it to a `double`.

You can fix this by making `sum` a `double`:

```
double sum = 0;
```

---

Also, sorting the entire range is needlessly inefficient for this problem. You only care about ignoring the first, and last 5% of the elements. To do this, you can use some algorithms to write:

```
double trimMean(vector<int> &arr)
{
    int length = arr.size();
    int five_pc = round(0.05 * length);
    
    // smallest 5%, and largest 95% in the correct relative positions
    std::nth_element(arr.begin(), 
                     arr.begin() + five_pc, 
                     arr.end());

    // largest 5% in the correct relative positions, 
    // while maintaining smallest 5%
    std::nth_element(arr.begin() + five_pc, 
                     arr.end() - five_pc, 
                     arr.end());

    return std::accumulate(arr.begin() + five_pc, 
                           arr.end() - five_pc, 
                           0.0) / (arr.size() - 2 * five_pc);
}
```